# html5 play only one file at a time and stop others? with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I have multiple audio files and i want to make it pause/stop all others if one plays.

This is how it looks like and i have jquery if that ease the solution:

```
<audio controls="">
<source type="audio/ogg" src="asdf.ogg"></source>
<source type="audio/mpeg" src="asdf.mp3"></source>
</audio>

<audio controls="">
<source type="audio/ogg" src="asdf.ogg"></source>
<source type="audio/mpeg" src="asdf.mp3"></source>
</audio>

<audio controls="">
<source type="audio/ogg" src="asdf.ogg"></source>
<source type="audio/mpeg" src="asdf.mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi in jQuery like this:

```
$("audio").on("play", function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    $("audio").each(function(i,el){
        if(!$(el).is(_this))
            $(el).get(0).pause();
    });
});
```

now you could try it your self in JS, and post it, to show that you tried something yourself!

Comment: ah, seems like i was lazy to try... :) works out of box thank you :)